# Perfrom click in Espresso test on view which is partly covered

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing tests in Espresso for Android and I can't figure out how to perform a click in Espresso on view which is partly covered by other views?

I want to perfrom that click only on part which is visible on screen, not on any of covering views.

Answer (score 0):

The *GeneralClickAction* has this constraint and the class is final so you can't override the *getConstraints* method.

You can create your own *ViewAction* based on the code of [GeneralClickAction](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java), without the *isDisplayingAtLeast(90)* check.